# How can I flatten value fields from a mapping table into a single column on an output report?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a mapping table structured similarly to the following:

```
ID       EntityID   EntityName  EntityCategory   ValueID
-----------------------------------------------------   
 1          1       System      Category1        50
 2          1       System      Category1        51
 3          1       System      Category1        52
 4          1       System      Category1        53
```

where ValueID is a FK to another table:

```
ID     Value
----------------
50     Red
51     Blue
52     Green
53     Yellow
```

I need to output a report for business users where each row in the report represents one primary-keyed row in this table, but the "Value" column is a flattened concatenation of the values related to ValueID, like this:

```
Name     Category    Possible Values
------------------------------------------------
System   Category1   Red | Blue | Green | Yellow
```

How can I write a query to produce this "flattened" output?

Comment: Search for `group_concat for sql server`. Here are few results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server https://groupconcat.codeplex.com/